# Laravel defining relationship

Tags: php, database, laravel, orm

Am still new to laravel

I have the following tables

```
user
   id
   first_name
   last_name

educations
  id,
  user_id  //references user id
  type
```

Now in my `user` model i would like to get a specific users educations which can be many

so a **user** can have many **educations** but each **education** belongs to a single **user**.
So in my `user` model i have

```
public function education()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ApplicantEducation','id','user_id');
}
```

In my `Education` model i have

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','id');
}
```

But the above fails, I cannot retrieve **user** specific **educations**

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Change `return $this->hasMany('App\ApplicantEducation','id','user_id');`
to `return $this->hasMany('App\ApplicantEducation','user_id', 'id');` you also ommit the `id` and `user_id`.

---

As your foreign_key is well formed, you can also rwite this simple code,

```
class User{
    public function education()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ApplicantEducation');
    }
}


Class Educations{
   public function user()
   {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:
in `User` Model:

```
public function educations()
    {
    return $this->hasMany('App\ApplicantEducation', 'user_id');
    }
```

in `Education` Model:

```
public function user()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here,

```
  $this->hasMany('App\ApplicantEducation','id','user_id');
```

In above statement first argument should be Model second should be foreign key and the third one is any other key from Education model.
Here, second and third arguments are not mandatory.

In User Model

```
class User...{
public function education()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\ApplicantEducation');
}
```

In Education Model

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Here, additional parameters are not mandatory might be your addition parameters creates issue,

and now you can retrieve your user with Education by

```
 $user = User::with('education')->get();
```

This can retrieve all the users with their education.
I hope it helps,Thank you, Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

**Education Model**

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id);
}
```

**User Model**

```
public function education()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ApplicantEducation');
}
```